# Regex Match strings starting and ending with

Tags: regex

Guys I want to write regex that matches all those strings starting with lower or ground and end with flat.. i.e. both these two would be captured in their entirety.

Example:

LOWER GROUND FLAT

GROUND FLAT

However, this does not seem to be doing the job:

^LOWER|GROUND\sFLAT$

Answer (score 3):

You should be using:

```
^(LOWER|GROUND)\s+.*?FLAT$
```

As you wrote it like

```
^LOWER|GROUND\sFLAT$
```

it is basically trying to match either

```
^LOWER
```

or

```
GROUND\sFLAT$
```

The parentheses change that to your original intent.

Comment: For this case i would use a non-capturing group ``^(?:LOWER|GROUND)\s+.*?FLAT$``